# Selecting an element through a html tag such as `data-element="#card__body"

Tags: intro.js

In Intro.JS, I would like to know how to potentially focus on an element whilst defining an elements selector from within the HTML like how its done with the JS version `element: document.querySelector('.card-demo')`

The closest example to being able to configure a step through HTML is in this example from the website https://introjs.com/docs/examples/basic/hello-world.

In that example `data-title="Farewell!" data-intro="And this is the last step!"` the data attributes are added to the html element that is being selected. However I would like to be able to define this separately and select the element after.

Using the same example from the website I would like to be able to define the step html separately potentially with a `data-` attribute that can define the class/ID that is to be selected.

E.g.
`<div data-attribute=".card__image" data-title="Farewell!" data-intro="And this is the last step!"` or a another way if possible.